# How to add AppContext Provider for document body in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-context, react-dom

I want to do like this. How to do this. Add the App context provider for document body. But it should not affect existing content.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(
<AppContextProvider>
  {document.body}
</AppContextProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appContextProvider function need to be construct first like below for example

```
import { useReducer, createContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { initialState, contextReducer } from 'yourOwnReducer';

const AppContext = createContext();

function AppContextProvider({ children }) { 
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(contextReducer, initialState);
const value = useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state]);

return <AppContext.Provider value={value}>{children} 
</AppContext.Provider>;
}

export default AppContextProvider;
```

then wrap the app component with the function after importing it

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./app";

import AppContextProvider from "./AppContextProvider";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <BrowserRouter>
    <AppContextProvider>
     <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
     </Routes>
    </AppContextProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```